# Microsoft Sync Framework mark client database as up to date

Tags: sql-server-2008, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I've developed an application using the Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 SDK and my current deployment method has been:

1. Make a backup of the unprovisioned database from a development machine and restore it on the server.
2. Provision the server followed by provisioning the client
3. Sync the databases
4. Take a backup of the synced database on the development machine and use that for the client installations. It is included in an InstallShield package as an SQL/Server backup that I restore on the client machine.

That works but on the client machine now I would also like to create a seperate test database using the same SQL/Server backup without doubling the size of the installation. That also works but of course because the client test version is no longer synced with the test version on the server it attempts to download all records which takes many hours over slower Internet connections.

Because integrity of the test database is not critical I'm wondering if there's a way to essentially mark it as 'up to date' on the client machine without too much network traffic?

After looking at the way the tracking tables work I'm not sure this is even possible without causing other clients to either upload or download everything. Maybe there is an option to upload only from a client that I've missed? That would suit this purpose fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further analysis of the data structures used by Sync Framework I determined there would be no acceptable way to achieve the result I was seeking without sending a significant of data between the client and server that would have approached what was required to do a 'proper' sync.

Instead I ended up including a seperate test database backup along with the deployment so that the usual PerformPostRestoreFixup could be performed followed by a sync in the normal manner the same as I was handling the live database.

Answer (score 1):

Everytime you take a backup of a provisioned database and restore it to initialize another client or replica, make sure you run PerformPostRestoreFixup after you restore and before you sync it for the first time.

Comment: Hi June, thanks but I do that in both cases. I initially had problems before I knew to do that so I'm confident it's being performed OK.

Comment: the client shouldn't be downloading all records if it has previously been synched. are you provisioning a new scope?

Comment: The live copy of the database has been synched and doesn't download anything. It's only the test version that is restored on the client from the same database backup, because it hasn't been synced with the server test database even though the data is the same. I know it's not a standard thing to do, but I'm looking for a way to 'cheat' and make it think the test database is up to date without syncing everything. I also tried copying live to test after provisioning, but after the post restore fixup it still seemed to realise it was different and download everythig.

Comment: if I understand your scenario, you have prod server and prod client, that's working fine. you want a test client and test server setup, simply back up either prod client or prod server, restore to both test client and test server, performpostrestorefixup, then sync.

Comment: Hi June, yes that will work. It's just the database is fairly hefty and I was trying to avoid having two backups in the client download if possible - some users are on slow satellite Internet and the like. If not possible I'll have to do that. If you'd like to update your answer to reflect that I'll accept in a few days if no other suggestions come along. The test database will also be used for training new users so it's required on every client machine.